# accessing the member of a class of pointer array of another class

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers, dereference

I'm trying to figure out how I can or why I can't access the member of this class. First I'll show you what works so you know what I'm thinking, then I'll show you what I can't seem to do.

What I can do is this: I have a class with a member. I make an pointer array of that class and make NEW pieces of it (through loop) and that's fine and all. I can also make another class with a similar array and even make NEW instances of that as well and initialize them, but when I try to access them, I have problems.

This code *almost* works fine:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class testClass{
    public:
    int number;
};

class testPoint{
    public:
    testClass testInstance;
    testClass *testclassArray[5];
    void makeArray();
    void setToI();
};

void testPoint::makeArray(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        testclassArray[i] = new testClass;
    }
}

void testPoint::setToI(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        (*testclassArray[i]).number = i;
    }
}

int main(void){
    testPoint firstTestPoint;
    firstTestPoint.makeArray();
    firstTestPoint.setToI();
//  EXCEPT FOR THIS LINE this is where I have problems
    cout << firstTestPoint.(*testclassArray[0]).number << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I know this should work becuase this works

```
int main(void){
    testPoint firstInstance;
    firstInstance.testInstance.number = 3;
    cout << firstInstance.testInstance.number << endl;
    // and this works
    return 0;
}
```

and this works

```
int main(void){
    testClass *testPointer[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        testPointer[i] = new testClass;
        (*testPointer[i]).number = i; 
    }
    cout << (*testPointer[0]).number << endl; 
    return 0; 
}
```

so why can't I access the members on the cout function the same way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is invalid syntax:

```
cout << firstTestPoint.(*testclassArray[0]).number << endl;
```

The most common way to write what you are trying to accomplish is:

```
cout << firstTestPoint.testclassArray[0]->number << endl;
```

But, if you prefer, you can also write:

```
cout << (*firstTestPoint.testclassArray[0]).number << endl;
```

(The second way is *far* less common.)

The `.` operator is used to access members of direct objects, e.g. `a.member` where `a` might be declared as `struct A a;`. The `->` operator is used to access members of indirect objects (aka pointers to objects), e.g. `b->member` where `b` might be declared as `struct B* b = new B();`.

Answer (score 2):

You are dereferencing the variable in an incorrect way.
Try doing

```
cout << firstTestPoint.testclassArray[0]->number << endl;
```

instead.
In the same way the second attempt, where it works for you, could also have been written:

```
out << testPointer[0]->number << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
cout << firstTestPoint.testclassArray[0]->number << endl;
```